# Express body-parsing checkboxes to array

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm pretty new to node / express and trying to create a simple form which can post data to Mongo database.

I'm struggling when trying to add a couple of checkboxes and saving the values to an array. For example

My form looks like this.

```
<form action="/addProduct" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label for="product-name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="product-name" name="product_name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="product-price">Price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="product-price" name="product_price">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
  </div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="bedroom">Bedroom<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="kitchen">Kitchen<br>

  <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />

  <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and server.js looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

MongoClient.connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function (err, database) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  db = database;
  app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
  });
});

app.post('/addProduct', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').save(req.body, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('saved to database');
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

I can't figure out how to include an array of categories on the object of req.body.  I would like it to show as

```
{ 
  product_name: 'light',                                                                                                                                                                                 
  product_price: '100',                                                                                                                                                                           
  description: 'its a light',                                                                                                                                                                            
  categories: [
      'bedroom',
      'kitchen'
   ] 
}
```

instead it's coming through as

```
{ 
  product_name: 'light',                                                                                                                                                                                 
  product_price: '100',                                                                                                                                                                           
  description: 'its a light',                                                                                                                                                                            
  categories:'kitchen'

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to rename the form parameters to `categories[]` which should group them into an array on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are using bodyParser on a `multipart/form-data` form. The [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) docs say "This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature."

If you remove `multipart/form-data` from your form and don't try to upload a file you will see that bodyParser is able to give you the format that you want - but then you won't be able to upload a file.

So you have to use an alternative to bodyParser that handles `multipart/form-data`. One alternative is [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). You just have to make two modifications to your code to use multer:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

// 1. require multer and define where you want the file to be uploaded
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

MongoClient.connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', function (err, database) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  db = database;
  app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
  });
});

// 2. Add middleware here with the name of the file input
app.post('/addProduct', upload.single('sampleFile'), function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').save(req.body, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('saved to database');
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The parser `body-parser` uses, [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs), should convert parameters with multiple values to an array, but if only a single value is provided (i.e. you only check one checkbox), `qs` just returns a string. You can force it to always return an array by including `[]` after the parameter name.

So, try changing all the `name="categories"` in your form to `name="categories[]"`.

---

Here’s an example that shows how `qs` parses form data:

```
const qs = require('qs')

// qs just returns a as a string.
console.log(qs.parse('a=1'))

// The [] make qs always return an array.
console.log(qs.parse('a[]=1'))
console.log(qs.parse('a[]=1&a[]=2'))
```

https://runkit.com/5818badec3b80300148b2c65/5818bbf9c3b80300148b2d24